# How to Hide Column Label Lightning Datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

Is there a way to hide or render labels based on a true/false value? For example, how to hide only the Phone label but display the other two labels? Is there a possible render value that can be set?

```
({
   init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
            { label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
            { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
            { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email'}
        ]);
        helper.getData(cmp);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label` is not mandatory. You can just use below as column object:

```
{ fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
```

**added based on comments**

You can filter the columns instead:

```
({  
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        let columns = [
            { label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
            { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
            { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email'}
        ];
        let mycolumns = columns.filter(col => col.label !== 'Phone');
        cmp.set('v.mycolumns',mycolumns);
        helper.getData(cmp);
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to not set one of those columns based on a true of false value? If i only wanted to display the Contact and Email Column would it be possible? ideally I'm looking to see if there is something such as this: { fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone', rendered: true}

Comment: we dont have `rendered` attribute but you can implement `filter` function. Added in answer